# Split a string consisting into leading numbers and everything after that

Tags: c#, regex, match

I have a list of files that must be copied to a new directory. All the information is in the filename. Each original filename consist of an [installation number][new filename]. So for example:

235623bob.txt

Here the installation number is 235623 and the new filename will be bob.txt. The installation number is 1 to 11 digits and the new filename never starts with a digit. It can however start with any other legal character and it can contain digits after the first character. So for example:

3245_6786bil54.txt

is 3245 as the installation number and _6786bil54.txt as the new filename. I have tried doing the following:

```
private void BtnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string inst_no = ""; // installation number
        string dest_filename = ""; // destination filename
        string dest_directory = "";

        string[] source_files = Directory.GetFiles(TxtSource.Text);

        // copy them to their new destination
        foreach (string file in source_files)
        {
            // source filename contains the instno and dest_filename.
            Match match = Regex.Match(file, @"(\d+)(\w+)"); 
            inst_no = match.Groups[0].Value; 
            dest_filename = match.Groups[1].Value;
            dest_directory = TxtDestination.Text + "\\" + inst_no;

            if (!Directory.Exists(dest_directory))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dest_directory);

            File.Copy(file, dest_directory + "\\" + dest_filename);
        }
    }
```

Here is the problem:

```
inst_no = match.Groups[0].Value; 
dest_filename = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

1253hans.txt should become

```
inst_no=1253
dest_filename=hans
```

But it is

```
inst_no=1253hans
filename=1253
```

What have I misunderstood with the group matches?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Groups[0]` always is the complete matched string. `Groups[1]` will be your first sub-group.
Your code should look like this:

```
inst_no = match.Groups[1].Value; 
dest_filename = match.Groups[2].Value;
```

Comment: Thanks. That was it. It does work as intended with that filename.